# How to verify that apple subscription offer is redeemed successfully for users with active subscription

Tags: in-app-purchase, storekit

We're implementing [subscription offers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/implementing_subscription_offers_in_your_app) in our app and all goes fairly well. However, if user has an active subscription while redeeming the offer, we're getting failed transaction from the payment queue, despite system popover states that "You're all set".

I'm not aware if it's documented anywhere, but I assume that the failed transaction in this case indicates, that user hasn't been charged. And yet, this is source of confusion — how do we know after all, if user redeemed the offer successfully or not?

What's more, the error property of the failed transaction, which is [expected](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymenttransactionstate/skpaymenttransactionstatefailed) to be used "to determine what happened" is actually *nil*. I'd like to consider the absence of error as an indirect evidence, that the transaction was actually successful, and yet I haven't seen any documentation to support this hypothesis.

I realise that subscriptions offers were introduced very recently, but maybe we're missing something here?

UPDATE: It looks like the `transaction.error` and `transaction.payment.paymentDiscount` are *nil* on the mac, but present on iPad (for same test account) for existing subscribers, though error message is still vague in the latter case:

> Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store}

Comment: Is this happening in sandbox?

Comment: Yes, we’re testing in sandbox.

Comment: Always recommended testing `StoreKit` on a physical device - sandbox is full of quirks and limitations. Can you confirm the same behavior on a physical device?

Comment: Yes, we’re always testing on real devices.

Comment: @enc_life, could you please confirm that you don't get some generic error, when subscription offer is redeemed by currently subscribed user (on the same subscription plan)?

Comment: @mikejd we have been testing at RevenueCat and are seeing the same behavior when resubscribing to a product using an offer: "You are all set" is displayed but an error is returned.

Comment: Same problem here. Did you find a fix?

Answer (score 2):

So this is just a quirk of sandbox. Crossgrades of an active subscription have never worked properly on Sandbox and they actually still don’t with offers. Although, they work fine on production.

However, you should still be able to test offers with a lapsed subscription. So, once the account has one completed cycle in that product, it should work.

You might want to check out [this](https://medium.com/revenuecat-blog/ios-subscription-groups-explained-8c5b8325d4ab) blog post on this.

How a user is charged depends on a bunch of factors.